# What to do if you are listed incorrectly as an administrative or technical contact for a domain?

Tags: domains, domain-registration

I recently got a letter in the mail from one of those sketchy "website listing services" that offer to submit your website to search engines for a fee. Before throwing it away I noticed that the domain name was not any of the ones I own. I looked up the name on networksolutions.com, and sure enough, my contact information (name, address, and phone number) is listed as the administrative and technical contact for the domain, along with an email address that is not mine.

Is there anything I can do to correct this? Is this associated with any known scams?

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to get technical control of the domain, as you are clearly the listed owner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It the domain is .com .net or .org then you should report the error to ICANN or InterNic. [Here's the form for doing so](http://wdprs.internic.net/). If it is a UK domain, look to Nominet. Other country domains have their own central registrars.

In addition you could try reporting it to the domain registrar that manages that domain. They will probably be keen to know about any fraud on their system though they might no show it outwardly.

Comment: Thanks, I contacted the abuse department of the registrar. The InterNic form you linked me to would not let me proceed because the domain name in question "is on hold". But hopefully contacting the registrar directly will work.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to run a few different credit reports on yourself as things like this are common with identity theft.

Comment: While this is good general advice, it doesn't answer my question of how to get the info removed from the listing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd contact networksolutions about this as soon as possible and explain the situation.

Comment: But doesn't networksolutions and other services like whois.net just report info from some central source?

Comment: Different organisations are responsible for running different domains. Things like whois know who is responsible for which and direct the query to the appropriate organisation. So it's not completely centralised.